# How do I determine if setPersistenceEnabled is already enabled?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

All works well. Once the app is running, and I press home and back to the app through the multitask viewer, it works well. But once it is running, and I press it's icon from the drawer, it crashes because it is calling again "setPersistenceEnabled()" when it is already running. So, how can I check if it is enabled before trying to enable it? My code:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseUser firAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);


    firAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    if (firAuth!=null) {
        // User is signed in.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Identificador.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    } else {
        // No user is signed in.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

};


}
```

Comment: This issue is [discussed here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/15) with the recommendation from a Firebase team member to use a singleton. An example is provided.

Comment: I think it is better a boolean than a singleton in this case. Singletons stay in memory long time after the app has been closed. But thank for answering, I haven't seen that thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you using the following lines of code:

```
private static boolean calledAlready = false;
if (!calledAlready) {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    calledAlready = true;
}
```

Comment: It works! I though that it would be kind of useless because each time I call SplashActivity it would be setting again "calledAlready" as false, but I put it outside the onCreate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run your app in debug mode.  Set a breakpoint at your SplashActivity onCreate() an run through your use case that crashes the app.  You'll see that SplashActivity onCreate() is invoked every time you launch your app after you leave it, because that's how activities work when they're exited and re-entered.

If you want to prevent repeated calls to setPersistenceEnabled(), you'll have to guard them against the invocation of your launch activity's onCreate() by setting some global variable to indicate that it's already been called, or put the call in a ContentProvider that gets created only once per process.  I suggest the latter.